# plasma pressure initial condition

Tags: laser, plasma-physics, metals

The authors in the paper below did a simulation of plasma plume evolution from a laser heated metal target. They used compressible transport equations and ideal gas EOS for Ar.

I am having difficulty understanding their initial condition. They say ", the initial internal pressure of plasma is assumed constant, 210 MPa.". How is this value determined or assumed. It is based on the temperature of the surface?

So, im thinking about the problem some more, and it seems the density is what should be known because when ablation occurs, phase transition occurs in the metal surface which generates a vapor.

Thanks

S. Harilal, G. V. Miloshevsky, P. K. Diwakar, N. L. LaHaye, and A.
Hassanein, Phys. Plasmas 19(8), [083504](http://scitation.aip.org/docserver/fulltext/aip/journal/pop/19/8/1.4745867.pdf?expires=1401132526&id=id&accname=441835&checksum=56FC49E2EB980524918E5FD7EBD840FA) (2012).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Page 9 [of the paper](https://engineering.purdue.edu/CMUXE/Library-publications-Hari.html) (see #26) the authors state,

> In the present modeling, we have chosen the initial value of pressure which gives the best fit to the experimental data. The criterion was to match the position of the shock front as a function of time.

The authors chose values that would give the best fit to the experimentally-determined values.

Comment: thanks.. I read on and I found it.. I am working on a simulation of the plasma plume expansion and I am trying to find a suitable b.c. for this problem without experimentally determined values

Comment: @mcodesmart: I don't see how can you validate your simulation if you don't have experimental values to confirm your results...

Comment: I am working with a colleague who has already measured the plasma plume using shadowgraphy. I want my simulation to not rely on experimental data but capture the physics from the equations.. The way they did it really takes away from their otherwise great experimental work, to be honest

Comment: I see. Well using the Sedov solution that the authors mention (combined with your colleague's shadowgraphy data) & the ideal gas law, you should be able to determine the plume's initial pressure.